# How do I animate a WPF control bound to a viewmodel property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a WPF app, which uses MVVM. When the users edits data, if certain conditions are met, they will need to fill in revision notes for auditing purposes. If they don't need to, I hide the revision notes textbox to keep the UI clear.

At the moment this is done by binding the Visibility property of the Grid that surrounds the textbox (and its label) to a bool property on the viewmodel. When the bool changes, the revsion notes textbox is hidden or shown as necessary.

This works fine, but the textbox just appears. I would like to animate it, so it grows from zero height to its default, or something similar.

Any idea how I would do this? I have done animation before, but this was always when I manually triggered the animation. In this case, I want to declare the animation in XAML, so it happens automatically when the binding changes.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You want a DataTrigger for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a DataTrigger to kick off an animation:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
       <Style>
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyVMBool}"
                         Value="True">

                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard >
                            <Storyboard>
                                <!-- DoubleAnimation on height or whatever -->
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <!-- you could animate close too if you wanted -->
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Gaz, that was exactly what I needed. Stupid thing is that I didn't find the answer by searching, nor did it show up as a suggested solution when I was typing the question, but as soon as I posted, I saw two other posts with exactly the same question in the "Related" links. Anyway, marked yours as an answer because it answered my question!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you solve it with a DataStateBehavior. Here's the MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn195678(v=vs.110).aspx. You could also take a look at the GoToStateAction.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that looks very useful. Unfortunately, this project is in VS2010, so I can't use that technique, but it looks worth considering for when we upgrade to VS2013.